# All of my getters and mutations stopped working after implementing Vuex modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am currently implementing Vuex and decided to implement modules.

Prior to doing so, everything was working properly and Vuex managed the state without an issue.

In all tutorials I have read and videos that I have watched, people, simply implemented modules and their apps always stat working right away, without any additional configuration.

In my app, however, all invoked mutations are now throwing an error that they cannot read from undefined.

Here is an example configuration of what I have: https://codesandbox.io/s/4zro5wzjz0

**UPDATE**: Bas van Dijk's answer was very valuable, but the issue was actually different - in the codesandbox I am not permitted to upload the entire app, therefore, I wasn't able to relate it properly. But in order for this post to have some value, I will explain what basically happened.

I was trying to interact between modules without importing them where they are to be used, therefore one of my modules was trying to manipulate values from another one, without it actually being there.

This happened, because I had to separate the initial Vuex object which was a big one by itself. A good conclusion for anyone who reads this post is - always start with scale in mind, it is way easier to scale an already separated configuration, than to have a monolithic peace of data, which you manually have to separate.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't imported your store in main.js. Therefore it was undefined.

```
import store from "./store";

new Vue({
  store,
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

You state also missed the `stakeControls` object

```
const state = {
  stakeControls: {
    enabled: true
  },
  stake: {
    value: 10
  }
};
```

I've also changed your store export into

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    Stake
  }
});
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/4zro5wzjz0

Comment: My apologies, it is now all in place and you would be able to recreate the issue